# How to use constant across go package

Tags: go

I'm writing my first go code and I'm trying to convince myself what I'm doing is not wrong.

anyway, here the project the tree structure.

```
.
├── helpers
│   └── common.go
├── logger
│   └── util.go
├── logger_example
└── runner.go
```

The main file to look over here is `logger/util.go` which look like this.

```
package logger

import (
  "log"
  "os"
)

type Logger struct {
  *log.Logger
}

func (l *Logger) Info(v ...interface{}) {
  l.SetPrefix("Info: ")
  l.Println(v...)
}

func (l *Logger) Error(v ...interface{}) {
  l.SetPrefix("Error: ")
  l.Println(v...)
}

func (l *Logger) Warn(v ...interface{}) {
  l.SetPrefix("Warn: ")
  l.Println(v...)
}

func (l *Logger) Debug(v ...interface{}) {
  l.SetPrefix("Debug: ")
  l.Println(v...)
}



func NewLogger() *Logger {
  logger := log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
  return &Logger{logger}
}
```

As you all can see, I'm just setting the prefix to `"INFO | WARN | ERROR | DEBUG"`

On the `main` package I have safely created a Logger instance and VOILA it worked.

Only until I decided to add a `helpers` package and now things do not look the way I wanted.

since the `logger.Logger` instance created inside `main` package, I have to pass it reference to every since package function where I want to invoke the logger statement. (see the below example ..)

```
// dodly_logger/logger/common.go
package helpers

import "dodly_logger/logger"
func Display(dodlyLogger *logger.Logger) {
  dodlyLogger.Info("Inside a helper package")
}
```

The Main package..

```
package main

import (
  logger "dodly_logger/logger"
  helpers "dodly_logger/helpers"
)

func main() {
  dodlyLogger := logger.NewLogger()
  dodlyLogger.Info("INFO MESSAGE")
  dodlyLogger.Error("ERROR MESSAGE")
  // Ehh, I have to pass the dodlyLogger ..
  helpers.Display(dodlyLogger)
}
```

Ok, now I know my GOLang knowledge is not complete hence I'm hoping people over here can point me how can I write this more clinically wherein I do not have to pass the reference of the `logger.Logger` to every function for which I need to log.

Comment: Outside of your question I suggest you read https://blog.golang.org/package-names
Your naming conventions aren't very Go like.

Comment: @reticentroot I love to know what are you referring above that is not correct or rather I say not very go like?

Comment: I linked you to the official Go documentation on Package naming.  Read the first ~4 paragraphs. However, to be explicate  `dodly_logger ` is not the proper way to name a Go package.  Most Go linters will catch that oversight as well. Go doesn't typical use underscores in package naming.  If need be use `-` over `_`

Comment: @reticentroot ok.

Answer (score 0):

Create a package level variable with `var`.

package main

```
import (
    logger "dodly_logger/logger"
    helpers "dodly_logger/helpers"
)

var dlogger logger.Logger

func init() {
    dlogger = logger.NewLogger()
}

func main() {
    dlogger.Info("Starting Main")
    a()
}

func a() {
    dlogger.Info("in a")
}
```

Comment: I have to do the same(the package level var, init method etc) inside the helper's package as well right?

Comment: If you're going to create a package level anything in Go and expect to be able to call or access the data in another package. The function, struct, var, or constant must be exported.
https://tour.golang.org/basics/3

Comment: Yes, set it again in subsequent helper packages.  Alternately, if you want the same logger across packages, you can have a method instead of NewLogger() that returns a new one, or an already created one.